# Wanted to connect POWERUSB in UBUNTU mate

Tags: c++, ubuntu, shared-libraries, raspberry-pi2

For my RESEARCH prototype I need to connect the powerusb (http://www.pwrusb.com/) smart switches and communicate with my Raspberry Pi 2 B. The Linux developer files are given in the powerusb website and they tested on UBUNTU. I am using Ubuntu MATE as well. Here is my sample code:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>  
#include <stdio.h>
#include "powerusb.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main (void)
    {
        void *sharedLibraryHandle;
        sharedLibraryHandle = dlopen ("/usr/lib/libpowerusb.so", RTLD_LAZY);
        if (!sharedLibraryHandle) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"%s\n", dlerror());
            exit(1);
        }else
        {
            printf("SUCCESS");
            }
        int (*SetPortPowerUSB_Address)(int, int, int); 
        //            - The function can be called by the following commands 
        SetPortPowerUSB_Address = (int (*)(int, int, int))dlsym(sharedLibraryHandle, "SetPortPowerUSB");
        (*SetPortPowerUSB_Address)(1, -1, -1);
                      //- The above code sets the powerusb port states to port1 = on, port2 = off and port3 = off.
    dlclose(sharedLibraryHandle);
    exit(3);
    }
```

The COMPILE has no error and I am using *-ldl* command while build. But after compilation while I run the program it shows following result:

```
/usr/lib/libpowerusb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

Which means it cannot connect to the library (I guess). Please help if someone have this experience. FYI, I already paste the library file there and run *ldconfig* after that.i.e. 
ls -l /usr/lib/libpowerusb.so showed 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26046 Apr 11 20:11 /usr/lib/libpowerusb.so

Thanks in ADVANCE

Comment: What it means is that the library does not exist. There's no such file.

Comment: Yes the error means there is no such library file in that path.

Comment: Splendid. Looks like you have your answer. Another mystery solved.

Comment: @Sam: However, the library file is already copied to that path. Still this error is showing.

Comment: So you say that "the library file is already copied to that path". Unfortunately, that's not documented anywhere. Instead of describing what you think is the situation, show it. Show the output of "ls -l /usr/lib/libpowerusb.so", to prove to the whole world that this library is really there. And if this filename is a symbolic link, repeat on the linked file. Just to prove to the rest of the world that you have a big mystery on your hands: the file really exists, but the operating system thinks it's not.

Comment: @sam: after giving the command it shows the following answer
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26046 Apr  11 20:11 /usr/lib/libpowerusb.so

Comment: Make sure the library is for the right architecture.